# INNER JOIN showing boths columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, inner-join

I have two tables with Covid-19 data (deaths and cases).

For cases

| date | region | age_group | sex | cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | data | data |

For deaths

| date | region | age_group | sex | deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | data | data |

I am aggregating the data to get daily cases and deaths by region and i am trying to insert it in a new table with four columns (date, region, cases_per_day, deaths_per_day). I tried the following to aggregate and join the data.

```
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT date, region, SUM(cases) AS cases_per_day 
FROM dbo.COVID19BEl
GROUP BY date, region) sub
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT date, region, SUM(deaths) AS deaths_per_day 
FROM dbo.DEATHSBE
GROUP BY date, region) c 
ON c.date = sub.date AND c.region = sub.region)
```

But it is returning this:

| date | region | cases_per_day | date | region | deaths_per_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | data | data | data |

The desired output is:

| date | region | cases_per_day | deaths_per_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | data |

Comment: Try removing date and region from: (SELECT date, region, SUM(deaths) AS deaths_per_day

Comment: I've flagged this question as "caused by a typo" since it is a basic SQL error. `INNER JOIN` includes all columns from both tables. You are using `SELECT *` which selects all columns. To exclude the `date` and `region` columns from one of the tables, you will need to change your `SELECT` clause. `SELECT sub.date, sub.region, cases_per_day, deaths_per_day FROM...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to remove duplicate columns from join in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808295/how-to-remove-duplicate-columns-from-join-in-sql)?

Comment: Yes it does, i am new to SQL. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only select columns you need:

```
SELECT
    sub.date , sub.region , sub.cases_per_day , c.deaths_per_day
FROM
((SELECT date, region, SUM(cases) AS cases_per_day 
FROM dbo.COVID19BEl
GROUP BY date, region) sub
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT date, region, SUM(deaths) AS deaths_per_day 
FROM dbo.DEATHSBE
GROUP BY date, region) c 
ON c.date = sub.date AND c.region = sub.region)
```